# Passing a collection to a mailable| Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

I am trying to get a mailable setup which has a collection of files. Mail controller looks like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use App\Document;
use App\Order;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use App\User;

class OrderComplete extends Mailable
{
use Queueable, SerializesModels;

public $user;
public $order;
public $documents;

/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(User $user, Order $order, Document $document)
{
    //
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->order = $order;
    $this->documents = $document;
}


/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->markdown('emails.customers.complete');
}
}
```

Controller calling the mailable looks like;

```
use App\Document;
    // other code...
$documents = Document::where('order_id', $orderId)
        ->where('product', 'like', '%response')
        ->get();
    Mail::to($customer)
        ->send(new OrderComplete($customer, $order, $documents));
```

But I keep getting this error:

`Type error: Argument 3 passed to App\Mail\OrderComplete::__construct() must be an instance of App\Document, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection given, called in /Users/ap/sites/propair/app/Http/Controllers/OrderController.php on line 253`

I'm pretty confused as I thought this should work?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function declaration:

```
public function __construct(..., Document $document)
```

means PHP will enforce that `$document` is an instance of `App\Document`.

If you want to pass it a collection instead, you'll need to do:

```
public function __construct(..., \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection $documents)
```

Comment: awesome, thank you very much, I did not realise that it worked like that. Stupid question, how does the collection know what attributes to have? if it gets them from the collection, why bother defining an instance (why can't the instance just get the attributes in the same way)?

Comment: A collection is basically (it has some useful helper functions, too) an array of models. It doesn't really "know" to have attributes - the attributes come from the individual models contained within.